# What is wrong with this OCAML function?

Tags: ocaml, reverse, cons

Here is my original code.

```
let rec reverse l =
   match l with 
   | [] -> []
   | (h::t) -> (reverse t) :: h
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cons `::` operator takes an element as left-hand argument and a list as right-hand argument. Here, you do the opposite which does not work.

The right way to add an element at the element at the end of a list is to use list concatenation:

```
let rec reverse l =
  match l with
  | [] -> []
  | h :: t -> (reverse t) @ [h]
```

That code is not optimal though, and you may want to make it [tail recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

Comment: How would one go about making this function tail recursive? I do not really understand the concept of tail recursion yet since I just started using Ocaml

Comment: Well, the idea of tail recursion is that the recursive calls of your function will always be the "last" action executed by your function. to speak in C terms, your calls to the function are always in the form `return myfun ()`. Here the last call of your function is to `@`. Tail-recursion is often allowed by adding an "accumulator" argument to your function that will store your intermediate result and be returned by your terminal cases (here the terminal case is `[]`).

Comment: You can lookup this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion

Comment: Not being tail-recursive is not the worst offender for the `reverse` function proposed. Its main problem is its quadratic complexity in the size of its argument. The tail-recursive version is linear.